# Cannot port forward

Tags: port-forwarding

I follow the guide on the web to port forward my minecraft server. But i didn't work. Here is an screenshot to[image]

I am using Aztech modem. I did port forward correctly as you can see the screenshot. Then, i use a port checker(http://canyouseeme.org) to check whether is my port open.

Comment: Was minecraft running a server at the time you did the test?

Comment: Yes -.- server run or do not run that doesn't matter right?

Comment: All the port forward does is pass packets through to the server.  If the server is not running, it will appear as though the port forward is not working even when configured correctly.  Can you access the server from your internal network (other than the machine it runs on)

Comment: I didn't try it. I can't access the server using my external ip address only internet ip address in the machine where my server run

Comment: What does that icon in the "drop" column mean?  If it means drop is active, then this would explain it.

Comment: For Aztech routers, you can click the icon in the "Drop" column to remove the rule (like a delete button) so that can't be the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your ISP is blocking the port.

Comment: I don't think so.. my friend near my place can port forward too

Comment: yes but my ISP blocks ports by default, this is an ISP-side firewall, however my ISP allows me to disable this in my account.

Comment: Test this with another port, like 80, with XAMPP or Apache.

Comment: @RobinGreen how to unblock it?

Comment: @rxt yes i try with other port, won't work.

Comment: @Jeremy I have no idea, that will be specific to your ISP.

Comment: Ask your ISP to be sure, but if port 80 does not work, it's likely that something else is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

some tips that might help:

- try to access the server from another pc on the same lan. is it working ?
- is the IP address of the server 192.168.1.6 as shown above ? it might change if you are using DHCP.
- are you trying to access the server from a remote pc over the internet, not from the same lan ?
- are you using the correct public ip address from the remote pc ? it might change if your ISP provides you dynamic IP, use whatismyip.com to make sure ip is correct at time of trial.
- to make sure it's not your ISP, quickest way is to call their helpdesk, another way is to setup bittorrent for example, and create another rule to forward to bittorrent port, and if it is still not running, then it could be ISP.

Comment: A router gives out IP addresses on the local network, using dhcp. Although these addresses might change, normally they stay the same for a long time. Only if the computer is reinstalled, renamed, or if the network card or mac address is changed, will the ip address change, as dhcp will see this as a new computer on the network.